# What does the "Optimize for full-screen video clip" option do in Zoom when sharing one's screen?

Tags: video, performance, screen-sharing, zoom-meeting

I read in the Zoom help about the option: [Optimizing a shared video clip in full screen](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/202954249-Optimizing-a-shared-video-clip-in-full-screen). What does the "Optimize for full-screen video clip" option do in Zoom when sharing one's screen?

I'm looking for an explanation more detailed than it optimizes for full-screen video clip but instead which technical features are activated to make it more optimal.

[image]

Comment: Only Zoom could tell you what it really does. I'd guess it switches to a different video codec.

Comment: As it is optimising for "full screen video clips" It probably switches the codec from a low motion, high efficiency mode (RDP like) to a high motion, fast but less efficient mode (video like). We can only guess the internal working of a proprietary tool that doesn't explicitly state what it is doing. Zooms help is patchy and vague at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question got downvoted here, I asked it on https://redd.it/levtiq, where [talones](https://www.reddit.com/user/talones) gave me the following  answer:

> It basically lowers the resolution so that the frame rate can be higher. If you have a basic or pro account it will most likely only be 360p video. With a business or education account you can get 720p or 1080p30.